# Calculating the adjustment translation to be applied after rotating and scaling so that operations pivot about a given point.

Tags: matrices, geometry, analytic-geometry, transformation

I have a matrix for transforming an image into a target frame.  The matrix is a function of a scale, $s$  rotation angle, $\theta$, and a translation that is applied after rotating, $tx, ty$.  The affine transform t is calculated by multiplying scale, then rotation then translation:

$$ t=
        \begin{bmatrix}
        s & 0 & 0 \\
        0 & s & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & 1 \\
        \end{bmatrix}
.
        \begin{bmatrix}
        cos(\theta) & sin(\theta) & 0 \\
        -sin(\theta) & cos(\theta) & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & 1 \\
        \end{bmatrix}
.
        \begin{bmatrix}
        1 & 0 & 0 \\
        0 & 1 & 0 \\
        tx & ty & 1 \\
        \end{bmatrix}
$$

This works well, I can adjust the scale, angle or translation to adjust the output image.

However the rotation and scale happens about the anchor point {0, 0}.  I would like to be able to scale about an arbitrary anchor point {rX, rY} (in the co-ordinate space of the target frame).

[image: translation]

What translation {tx, ty} should be applied (after scale and translation) so that the image rotates about {rX, rY} (instead of {0,0})?

I have looked at [similar questions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/5805/scaling-at-an-arbitrary-point-and-figuring-out-the-distance-from-origin) but I can not make it work for this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard scaling and rotation matrices pivot point is $(0,0)$. To adjust it, compose your transformation with appropriate translation before and after the main matrix.

Suppose you want to rotate your picture with pivot at $(p_x,p_y)$, then first translate $(-p_x,-p_y)$, then rotate and finally translate back $(p_x,p_y)$

$$
\begin{bmatrix}x'\\y'\\1\end{bmatrix}=
        \begin{bmatrix}
        1 & 0 & p_x \\
        0 & 1 & p_y \\
        0 & 0 & 1 \\
        \end{bmatrix}
\cdot
        \begin{bmatrix}
        cos(\theta) & -sin(\theta) & 0 \\
        sin(\theta) & cos(\theta) & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & 1 \\
        \end{bmatrix}
\cdot
        \begin{bmatrix}
        1 & 0 & -p_y \\
        0 & 1 & -p_x \\
        0 & 0 & 1 \\
        \end{bmatrix}
\cdot
        \begin{bmatrix}x\\y\\1\end{bmatrix}
$$

or for row-vector representation of points (which seems you are using)

$$
\begin{bmatrix}x,y,1\end{bmatrix}
\cdot
        \begin{bmatrix}
        1 & 0 & 0 \\
        0 & 1 & 0 \\
        -p_x & -p_y & 1 \\
        \end{bmatrix}
\cdot
        \begin{bmatrix}
        cos(\theta) & sin(\theta) & 0 \\
        -sin(\theta) & cos(\theta) & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & 1 \\
        \end{bmatrix}
\cdot
        \begin{bmatrix}
        1 & 0 & 0 \\
        0 & 1 & 0 \\
        p_x & p_y & 1 \\
        \end{bmatrix}
=
        \begin{bmatrix}x',y',1\end{bmatrix}
$$

The same will work with scaling. Also, if both your scaling and rotation use the same pivot point, then you can get rid of the inner translation as these cancel out, i.e.

$$
        \begin{bmatrix}
        1 & 0 & -p_y \\
        0 & 1 & -p_x \\
        0 & 0 & 1 \\
        \end{bmatrix}
\cdot
        \begin{bmatrix}
        1 & 0 & p_y \\
        0 & 1 & p_x \\
        0 & 0 & 1 \\
        \end{bmatrix}
=
        \begin{bmatrix}
        1 & 0 & 0 \\
        0 & 1 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & 1 \\
        \end{bmatrix}
$$

I hope this helps $\ddot\smile$

Comment: Thank you for this.  The only issues is I would like to keep the same pipeline i.e. scale -> rotate -> translation.  Is there a way to calculate the translation required just at the end, without any pre-multiplication?

Comment: For example perhaps I can use the method that you described, then pull out the translation component from the calculated matrix?  Not sure if that would work tho?

Comment: One more thing... sorry to add so many questions! ... is the pivot point in your example (Px, Py) in the co-ordinates of the original image?  If so, how do I calculate (Px, Py) from the point in the target frame co-ordinates - (rX, rY)?

Comment: @Robert Sorry, I don't have time to provide you with all the details. Experiment with it, and you will know. It's possible to keep the same pipeline, but it would be the same computation, only in different order. The easiest way to do it, is to put your pivot point through the rotation and scaling transformations, and calculate the difference from where it should be to where it is, that will give you the necessary translation, which you can later put into your pipeline. Also, you can multiply the matrices by hand and type in only the formulas (but it is less maintainable). Good luck!

Comment: Got this working, thanks! :)

Comment: What if I only have scaling?

Comment: @AaronFranke Then just replace the rotation matrix with the scale matrix.